# What is the fastest way to vectorize a 2 parameter .loc update?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

Let's say that I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': [1, 2, 3], 'm': [4, 4, 7]})
df.loc[df['m']==4,'n']=1
```

Running this .loc function on a relatively small dataset (~50,000 int32 samples) is taking 11ms. Is there any way I can speed this up? I'm hoping to get the same operation down to between 10-100μs.

## Update

I've edited the above example to be a bit more concise.

After testing the suggested methods, the fastest was :

`df['n'].values[df['m'].values == 4] = 1`

After applying it to a ~50,000 sample data set, this solution ran 244 times faster than the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches. You may wish to consider modifying the underlying NumPy array. However, this is not a documented or officially recommended method.

```
# Python 3.6.5, Pandas 0.19.2, NumPy 1.11.4
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10**5),
                   'm': np.random.randint(0, 10, 10**5)})

%timeit df.loc[df['m'] == 4, 'n'] = 1                              # 1.3 ms
%timeit df['n'].values[df['m'].values == 4] = 1                    # 436 µs
%timeit df['n'] = np.where(df['m'].values == 4, 1, df['n'])        # 751 µs
%timeit df.iloc[df['m'].values == 4, df.columns.get_loc('n')] = 1  # 880 µs
%timeit df.loc[df['m'].values == 4, 'n'] = 1                       # 1.12 ms
%timeit df['n'] = df['n'].mask(df['m'].values == 4, 1)             # 1.34 ms
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer jpp! The fastest method was `%timeit df['n'].values[df['m'].values == 4] = 1  `

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for a more efficient solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': np.random.choice(range(5), 100_000), 
                   'more_numbers': np.random.choice(range(5), 100_000)})

%timeit df.loc[df.more_numbers==4,'numbers']=1
7.09 ms ± 658 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit np.where(df.more_numbers == 4, 1, df.numbers)
547 µs ± 20.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

So you could instead do:

```
df.numbers = np.where(df.more_numbers == 4, 1, df.numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

So just do with `values`

```
%timeit df.values[df['more_numbers']==4,0]=1
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop
%timeit df.loc[df['more_numbers']==4,'numbers']=1
1000 loops, best of 3: 692 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I was able to make your suggestion slightly faster by changing it to `df.values[df['more_numbers'].values==4,0]=1`

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df.numbers=np.where(df['more_numbers']==4,1,df.numbers)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Pleasure Daniel :)